# Attachment acf custom field data(wp-json) in Gallery Field

Tags: json, wordpress, gallery, advanced-custom-fields

I have a question about showing (attachment) custom field data(wp-json) in the gallery field in post by wp-json.

The custom field (media_docu_scource)& (media_docu_description)I made in Attachment could not be shown in the ACF gallery field, which I made the gallery field in post.

Please see the attached image 
[image]
I have installed WP REST API (WP API) & ACF to WP REST API

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin developer has answer my question
please see the following website
https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-wp-rest-api/issues/1